# Change text in TextView

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView element in my "activity_main.xml":

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/my_best_text"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        />
```

and want to change the text inside this TextView with the id "text1"! I have tried in my "MainActivity.java" something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);
    }
```

How to do that correctly?

EDIT

My App crashed with these two lines

```
TextView txtView= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1));
txtView.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the text at another point in your program, you can use `setText`

For your text that you provided, you want to change it to something like this:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    TextView txtView= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1));
    txtView.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);
}
```

Also, I would advise putting this line: `TextView txtView= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1));` in your `onCreate` for your intent if you have one, and then use the second line: `txtView.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);` in your `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` or anywhere else you need it.

Comment: The two "TextView" in this snippet is displayed "red" in Android Studio and if I move with the mouse over it Android Studio show the tooltip "cannot resolve symbol TextView" Whats wrong?

Comment: sorry I forget to import android.widget.TextView;

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
final TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
textview.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, the common way is:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textView1.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis will work You can change your java code to :

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1); 
    text.setText("Menu item selected -> " + position);

}
```